# Copy row from table if a cell in a specific column changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am searching for a VBA code that:
If I change the second column in my table, on sheet1 it copies that row and paste it in sheet2.
Every time on the next blank row.
I know it has to be something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("A1:E19"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
    End If
End Sub
```

But how do I change this specific `range(A1:E19)` to a column in a table?

And after, how do I tell to copy that specific row that has the changed cell?

Hope someone can and will help me out :)

Comment: `Me.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange`?

Comment: What does Me stand for?

Comment: It refers to the sheet that this code is running against.

Answer (score 0):

The Worksheet_Change function gets invoked (and executed) when there is a change in one of the cells in the sheet. The "Target" variable that is used in your function is a range of cells (most often just 1 cell) that were changed. Therefore to check the column of the cell that was changed, you can simply reference one of attributes of the "Target" variable.

For example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
    ...
```

The same way you can reference the row that you want to copy.

```
Target.Row
```

According to your description, the last two things you need to do are:

1. Find a last row of the second sheet so you can copy to the last_row + 1.
2. Learn how to do copy and paste in VBA

Tutorials on how to do both of these things are easy to find via Google.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I don't know what I am doing wrong, but all the codes that I try.. Nothing happens. Don't get a warning that something is not correct, but nothing happens at all.

Comment: Open "Locals" window (View menu on the top -> Locals Window). That will show you values for your variables. Then walk step by step through the code the see what the values are and what is the logic executed by your code. To step through the code, use keyboard shortcuts associated with "Step Over" and "Step Into" in the Debug menu.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this work for you

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Lrow, Lrow2 As Long
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet
'get last row of a column with values
'change the number 1/2 depending on the column of your table

Lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set sheet2 = Worksheets("sheet2")
Lrow2 = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row


'Lets supose that your colum table starts in range A1

If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("A1:A" & Lrow), Target) Is Nothing) Then
    'copy the value of the modified range to sheet 2 in column 2
    With sheet2

        .Range("B1:B" & Lrow2).Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Value

    End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jairo, do you know why this happens.. It copies all the columns, including the first 5 that are hidden. But when I have an autofilter active, it doesn't copy these 5 columns that are hidden. When I unhide them and have autofilter active it does copy them